# How to programatically find and distinguish triggers in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that updates a spreadsheet. It runs every morning and, every time it does, it creates 4 triggers. 
I also have time-driven triggers, which I want to keep there.

Since there is a limit on the triggers, I need to remove the triggers created by the function (while maintaining the other ones). However, when I run this:

```
function Triggers () {
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers())
}
```

I get this as a response:

```
 [Trigger, Trigger, Trigger, Trigger, Trigger, Trigger, Trigger, Trigger]
```

How can I identify, of these, the ones created by that function so I can eliminate those only?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
function Triggers () {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
  for (i in triggers)
    if ((triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()) == "createStats") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i])
    }
}
```